# Playing sound from source Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm an amateur programmer and I'm trying to create a button on Chrome as an extension that will play a clip when pressed. I'm not entirely convinced I'm doing this correctly. Any help would be much appreciated. Even a point in the right direction would be great. I am loading the .json through Chrome using the unpacked extension loader.

The problem that Chrome is telling me is that the "Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 10, column: 2, Unexpected data after root element."

```
{
  "name": "EzWinEzLyfe",
  "version":"1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "DUH DA NA NAH",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  }
}
var myAudio = new Audio();
myAudio.src = "C:\Users\Eduardo\Desktop\Hello World/win.mp3";
myAudio.play();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to put your code in your manifest. You need to instead create a background section, like this:

```
"background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] }
```

Then create a background.js file and put it in the same folder as the manifest. Since you want the sound to play when you click the extension icon, put the sound code inside a icon click listener, like this:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
  new Audio("win.mp3").play()
})
```

Chrome extensions cannot directly access a user's filesystem, so make a copy of the audio and put it in the extension folder.

Here are some dev docs: [Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview), [Manifest File Format](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest), [Background Pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages), [HTMLAudioElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement)

Answer (score -2):

It doesn't appear that your browser_action property is formatted properly, at least according to this  [Chrome browserAction](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction)

```
      "browser_action": {
          "default_icon": {                    // optional
            "19": "images/icon19.png",           // optional
            "38": "images/icon38.png"            // optional
          }
```

Comment: According to that link, his browser action is correct.

Comment: My mistake, there are a few ways to declare it.